# gcloud crashed HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: gcloud

gcloud auth login not coming back to terminal on **macos**:

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError):
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x105347130>:
> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))

gcloud auth login working fine on my other PC **windows bash terminal** with same Wifi.

Given read & write permissions to everyone of folder *google-cloud-sdk*

Comment: Did you reboot the mac and try again?

Comment: i had format my mac hard disk and still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your ISP, Airtel India. Use a VPN, and it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I tried both browser and no-browser options, but kept getting the problem. To resolve this, I connected my corporate VPN and the problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

on MacOS goto your icloud settings and enable Private Relay(Beta)
which resolved my problem